# Sublime text says: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: makefile, sublimetext3, text-editor

I'm making my first project on a real text editor, Sublime Text.

All I have are two files: index.html and script.js

In index.html, all I have is

`<h1>hello world</h1>`

In script.js, all I have is

`console.log("hello?")`

Then I hit "Build System > Automatic" and then "Build"

I get the error "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: it's unclear what you expect to happen when you have an HTML file and a javascript file and you try to "run" or "build" it, but the build system being selected is `Make` for executing things using the `make` tool, which is almost certainly not what you want. That build will only be selected automatically if you have a file named `Makefile` in your project somewhere.

Comment: You don't need to build anything. However, in order for your JS to run, you need to include it in your HTML file. They don't run just by existing.